# Laravel 'many to many' user associates with many posts?

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, posts

In PostsController

```
public function store()
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        ]);

        auth()->user()->publish(
            new Post(request(['title', 'body']))
        );

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

in user.php

```
 public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function publish(Post $post)
    {
        $this->posts()->save($post);
    }
```

the thing is after login I am seeing the all posts associate with only logged in user but i want many posts to many user relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user model must be like this

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
       public function Posts()
       {
           return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
       }
}
```

The post model must be like this.

```
class Post extends Model
{

        public function users()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
        }
}
```

The migration class for user

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                  $table->increments('id');
                  $table->string('name');
                  $table->string('email')->unique();
                  $table->string('password');
                  $table->rememberToken();
                  $table->timestamps();
              });
    }

   /**
        * Reverse the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function down()
       {
           Schema::dropIfExists('users');
       }
}
```

The migration class for Post

```
class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
         Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Also u need a pivot table. The table name must be - user_post

```
class CreatePostUser extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     * user_post
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_user', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
                  $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
                            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
                                ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

                            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
                            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')
                                ->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_post');
    }
}
```

Please refer this link for more details - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

I hope you find this useful!

Comment: seeing this error 

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'logos.post_user' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `post_user` (`post_id`, `user_id`) values (1, 1))

Comment: Can you please post your code in action ? I want to see, how you are saving the data.

Comment: In User.php

`public function publish(Post $post)
    {
        $this->posts()->save($post);
    }`

In PostController

 `public function store()
    {
     $this->validate(request(), [
      'title' => 'required',
      'body' => 'required'
     ]);

     auth()->user()->publish(
            new Post(request(['title', 'body']))
        );

     return redirect('/');
    }`

Comment: oh.. Sorry can you please change the pivot table name to post_user in this case. The table name must be - post_user.

Comment: I already added user_post after adding this I am seeing this error

Comment: Sorry can you please change the pivot table name to post_user in this case. The table name must be - post_user. I edited my answer. Please check it again

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help

Comment: I just have one more issue regarding the post associated with user means their username on their post

Comment: To do that, u must have one-to-many relation between post and user  

Add this function to your post model

public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

Testing, if it works...
$post = Post::find(1);
$created_by = $post->user->name;

Comment: {{ Auth::user()->first_name }}
this is in blade
but this is only for current user I want particular  first_name to particular post

Comment: Yes, It is possible as it is in my last answer.

Comment: where do i defined this ?

Comment: Add this function to your post model public function user() { return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); }